# Xcode - How do I Detecting screen size of iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two xibs, one for the iPhone 4 and one for the iPhone 5; 3.5 inch and 4 inch.  I simply want to put some code that tells the app which to load.  I have this code which is supposed to do the job:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone))
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
    //Load 3.5 inch xib
    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
        //Load 4 inch xib
    }
```

I put it in the ViewController.M(is that where I put it?) and the build fails saying there is a parse issue expected identifier of "("
Can anyone help me with this simple fix? Thanks!

Comment: `if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)` use this line

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: the problem is in your code you have added extra ) just remove it it will work

Comment: @MartinR Not sure what close reason should be used for that.

Comment: @Sumurai8: There is no "pre-configured" close reason for typo questions (anymore), compare http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192846/which-close-reason-should-i-use-to-close-typo-questions-now.

Comment: Remove `if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone))
{`, put the code in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 18):

add below line in your prefix.pch file...this is the simplest way to check screen size, no need to make extra lines of code...

```
#define   IsIphone5     ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

now whereever you want to check screen size , just make condition like below, and you can do whatever you  want....

```
 if(IsIphone5)
{
    //your stuff
}
else
{  
  //your stuff
}
```

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is about the fact that the given code doesn't compile.

Comment: this may not the answer of the question, but this answer is the simplest and smartest way to detect screen size my friend.Why should write 3 or 4 lines of code for just detecting the screen size..

Comment: @NiravPatel can you explain in brife why it is smart answer?

Comment: @DhavalBhadania :Ghare aavje explain karis....

Comment: @NiravPatel but it not working in my code ....can u explain how to used it ...really yar nahi chal tu ?

Comment: +1 Perfect... worked by just copy pasting that Macro code. Thanks

Comment: @NiravPatel  Best most effective answer on this topic EVER!

Comment: yes +1 for good answer

Answer (score 4):

put this condition

```
if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    // This is iPhone 5 screen
} else {
    // This is iPhone 4/4s screen
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is about the fact that the given code doesn't compile.

Comment: @BradConidaris : When you're loading your nib for 3.5 or 4 inch screen you can check this condition and load your nib accordingly

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Confused about nibs

Comment: @BradConidaris : When you're pushing your viewController with navigation at there you can check for this condition and load the xib file of your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

remove extra ")" at the end from this line

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this remove last Bracket

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
      CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
      if(result.height == 480)
      {
            //Load 3.5 inch xib
      }
      else if(result.height == 568)
       {
             //Load 4 inch xib
       }
}
```

Comment: -1 for adding a duplicate answer.

Comment: Which file do I put the code in? Appdelate.m?