# How can I get the Xcode storyboard and the iPhone Retina (3.5-Inch) simulation to use the correct xcassets images?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, storyboard, xcasset

Weird problem here which may be a bug in Xcode...

Using an Xcode 5.1.1 storyboard with auto layout, I am working on the design of a view controller that contains a full iPhone 4 sized UIImageView that references an xcassets image set. The xcassets image set includes 1x and 2x iPhone 3.5-inch images, and an iPhone 4 R4 image.

Problem 1: Once I set the Image View Image for the UIImageView in the utilities panel using a View Mode of Aspect Fit, the storyboard shows the smaller iPhone 3.5 image with white spaces at the top and the bottom of the view instead of the iPhone 4 image which would fill the entire storyboard representation of the view, as they are the same size since Xcode infers an iPhone 4 sized screen in the storyboard.

Problem 2: If I ignore problem 1 and run the program using the iPhone Retina (4-Inch) simulation, the applications selects the correct image size from xcassets and everything seems fine. However, if I run the simulation using the iPhone Retina (3.5-Inch) simulation, the applications also selects the correct sized image, but pushes the images down and display white space at the top of the page.

Before I start hacking around these problems, I thought I would reach out and see if anyone else has experienced either of these issues. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 4" screen with xcassets not pulling correct image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056426/iphone-4-screen-with-xcassets-not-pulling-correct-image)

Comment: i read that question before i submitted. my question relates to getting the xcassets images to work in the storyboard, and my r4 image is loading fine in simulation, but the 3.5 image fails

Comment: What version of iOS are you supporting?